# RIPE: How to lookup IP Address using REST API based on descr attribute

Tags: powershell

When I use Full Text Search from RIPE (https://apps.db.ripe.net/db-web-ui/fulltextsearch) for search companies contained with its description word "rejonowy" and select options:

- "Search only within the following objects:inetnum"
- "Search within the following fields:descr"

I got 132 results.

But when I try to make this query with Rest API I got only 2 results.
Here is my query:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{"Accept"="application/json"} -uri "http://rest.db.ripe.net/search?source=ripe&object-type=any&query-string=rejonowy" -Method Get
```

Does anyone know where I make mistake in this query?